# Two Nested Foreach loop with large data frame out of memory

Tags: r, foreach, out-of-memory

I'm new to R. I have two dataframes (df_A (with 20000 obs, 500 variables) and df_B (with 400000 obs, 500 variables). I'm performing a cor.test with wto nested foreach loops. Here are the lines:

```
  numCores <- detectCores()  
  cl <- makeCluster(20)  
  registerDoParallel(cl)

ptm = proc.time()
results <- foreach(i=1:nrow(df_A), .combine = 'rbind', .packages="foreach") %dopar% {
  foreach(j=1:nrow(df_B), .combine='rbind', .packages="foreach") %do%{
    myTest = cor.test(as.numeric(unlist(df_A[i,])),as.numeric(unlist(df_B[j,])),method="pearson")}}
print(proc.time() - ptm)
stopCluster(cl)
```

It seems to work fine with smaller data.frames, but it gets out of memory with these two large data.frames.
I am trying to solve this issue for quite some time already, but my brains are burned. I came with two possible solutions, that I do not if they are possible:

1) send to "results" only the two columns (p.value and estimate) that I am interested on (the cor.test produces 9 columns for each correlation analysis, which should consume memory).

2) send to file the results in chunks every X iterations.

I do not know how or if these solutions are posible. I would apreciate any ideas!!

Comment: I would remove the inner foreach loop. It will not speed up the process. The first foreach will dispatch to separate nodes. Each node will do the inner loops and return the results. This will probably save you some memory since you will have less R instances. Small comment on your code, do you really have 20 cores available? If not I would just go for the number detected.

Comment: 1. read how to ask good questions on `r` tag on SO, it will helps to get good answers. 2. didn't investigate your code because it is not reproducible, but you may try data.table, it is cpu and **memory** efficient version of data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
@Stereo: If I remove the inner foreach loop, it won't iterate between the lines of the second data.frame. Am I wrong? About the cores, yes, we have 24 cores availables at work, so I dedicate 20 to this task. I have no problem with speed (I can let the server running for quite some time). My problem is the out of memory issue.

Comment: @jangorecki. Thanks a lot. I will read the SO tag. about the reproducibility issue. the files containing the data.frames have 4 gb and as the problem that I am facing is a memory issue I do not know how could I send you the dataframes. Is there a way to do it? I am trying now the data.table.

Comment: @Matias, you will have to rewrite the foreach to a for loop but that is about it. I would recommend to post the header of your data if possible so that we know what kind of problem you are facing. Also update your question with additional info such as OS, architecture, data size, data format and R version.